# Checking to see how many times a number appears in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I am new to programming in C and I would like to figure out how can I see if a user enters a number between 1 to 20 and checks to see if the number entered by user appears in the array of random numbers between 1 and 20 which then displays to the user that the number they have entered is appeared "number of times".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 30
int main(void)
{
    int nums[N];
    int numAppear, i, count = 0;
    int n;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      nums[i] = rand()%20 + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 20 to be found (<=0 for exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n <= 0) {
            printf("End\n");
            break;
        }
        else if (nums[j] == n) {
            count++;
            printf("%d appears %d times \n" , n, count);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d appears %d times \n" , n, count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should take the input outside the loop. What's `j` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the user for a number on every iteration through the loop and printing the count on every iteration.  Also, you should be indexing `nums[i]`, not `nums[j]`

Move the input before the loop and the output after.

```
printf("Enter a number between 1 and 20 to be found (<=0 for exit): ");
scanf("%d", &n);

if (n <= 0) {
    printf("End\n");
    return 1;
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == n) {
        count++;
    }
}
printf("%d appears %d times \n" , n, count);
```